# Dividing double by 0 returns infinty

Tags: java, eclipse

The code basically gives me infinty and the sting undefined. I only need undefined. I understand why its giving infinity but dont understand how to get rid of it. I cant use an exception as the error should only print undefined and nothing else.

```
double divide;
double a;
double b = 0;

if(args.length > 3){
    System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
}
else if(args.length == 1){
    System.out.println("Argument count mismatch");
}
else{
    a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    divide = a / b;
    System.out.println(divide);
    if (b == 0) {
        System.out.println("Undefined");
    }
}
```

Comment: `I cant use an exception as the error should only print undefined and nothing else.` So why can't an exception only print `undefined`?

Comment: Stop printing both things?

Comment: You're performing the division before you test the value of `b`. Test the value first and don't perform the division if `b` is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way in addition to Elliott Frisch's way is to check for positive or negative infinity using the constants in the [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) class.

```
if (divide == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || divide ==  Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
{
    System.out.println("Undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test the result with [`Double.isInfinite(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isInfinite%28double%29) (and you might also want to use [`Double.isNaN(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN(double)) and something like,

```
double a = 10;
double b = 0;
double divide = a / b;
if (Double.isInfinite(divide) || Double.isNaN(divide)) {
    System.out.println("Undefined");
} else {
    System.out.println(divide);
}
```

Output is

```
Undefined
```